# Replace all tags except one with RegExp in Java

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have got the following problem. I want to **delete all substrings** which **start with `<`** and **end with `>`**, **except** the substring **`<back>`**.

Example: `<apps> <up> <down> <capital> ...` should be deleted, but not `<back>`.

I am sure this works with **RegExp** and `String.replace()`, but I don't know how.

Currently, I have figured out this:

```
line = line.replaceAll("<[^<]*>", "");
```

The **problem** is, that this **also deletes** the **`<back>`-substring!**

I hope someone of you knows a solution.

Thank's for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `(?!<back>)<[^<]*>` , `line = line.replaceAll("(?!<back>)<[^<]*>", "");`

`(?!<back>)` (negative look ahead) do not match the tag `<back>`

[**RegEx Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/7LpN1s/1)

Comment: The `(?!<back)<[^<]*>` solution will not match those `<...>`-like strings that have a word *starting with* `back`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks , i have improved it and just writing the description , let me hit to show

Comment: Thank you all for your fast answers, this one works better, the first one deleted some other characters. The RegExp-Demo is really helpful!

Comment: @MichaelGierer glad that me and Wiktor Stribiżew could help , happy coding

Comment: This solution contains redundant parts and can be shortened further.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yours new one is shortened and i guess OP should take look at it

Answer (score 3):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
line = line.replaceAll("<(?!back>)[^<>]*>", "");
                         ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ZruDp/3).

The pattern matches:

- `<` - the `<` symbol
- `(?!back>)` - that is not followed with `back>` (this negative lookahead, being a zero-width assertion, only checks for the text to the right of the current location, but the text is not consumed)
- `[^<>]*` - zero or more chars other than `>` and `<`
- `>`  - a `>` symbol.

Comment: What characters did this solution remove? I updated to match only from `<` to the closest `<` excluding both `<` and `>`.